# Clarifcation of Resnick's use of $\uparrow$.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am studying Sidney Resnick's "Probability Path". On page 32 is a proof of a set theoretic version of Fatou's lemma. The first part of this proof reads like so:

$P(\liminf_\limits{n \to \infty} A_n) = P(\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \uparrow (\bigcap_\limits{k \ge n} A_k)) = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \uparrow P(\bigcap_\limits{k \ge n} A_k) \le \liminf_\limits{n \to \infty} P(A_n)$

Where $A_n \in \mathcal{B}$, a $\sigma$-algebra.

I'm having trouble understanding what Resnick means by the $\uparrow$ in this context. He does introduce the symbol in the first chapter but does so as notation to denote a non-decreasing series. Here it seems to be acting as some sort of operator upon $(\bigcap_\limits{k \ge n} A_k)$ and then $P(\bigcap_\limits{k \ge n} A_k)$.

Can anyone clarify as to how I should read this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an operator, and it's not necessary to write it. It is just to make it clear that it is the limit of a non-decreasing sequence.

In the first case, $(\cap_{k\geq n}A_k)_{n\geq 1}$ is non-decreasing with respect to the inclusion relation.

In the second, $(P(\cap_{k\geq n}A_k))_{n\geq 1}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As $n$ grows, the sequence of sets $\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$ increases, since we're intersecting over a smaller collection of sets.